# CSS HTML - Text won't overlay to footer background color

Tags: html, css

this is my big problem im so stressed that the link text won't overlay to the background color of the footer please help im newbie to this :] im using html and css. and please correct any codes if possible you see wrong codes because im just starting from scratch. thanks

[picture of the problem click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sj9o.jpg)

```css
* {
 background-color: #CEF6CE;
 font-family: calibri;
 margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
 background-color: white;
 height: 635px;
 width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.login {
 background-color: red;
 width: 300px;
 height: 350px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 margin-left: 450px;
 margin-right: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.footer {
 background-color: #4A4A4A;
 width: 5000px;
 height: 5000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: fixed;
 font-size: 13px;
}
a:link {
 background-color: transparent;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Insight - Community Portal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\homepage_design.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id = "main">
 
 <div class = "wrapper">
 
 <div class = "login">
 School <br> Community Portal
 </div>
 
 </div>

 <div class = "footer">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
 <tr>
  <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">About</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;</td>
  <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">Help</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;</td>
 </tr>
 </table> 
 </div>
 
 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
* {
  background-color: #CEF6CE;
  ...
}
```

The * selector makes this styling apply to all tags. For the footer, you override it with the following styling:

```
.footer {
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  ...
}
```

I removing the background-color from the "*"-styling, and assigning it to the body-tag instead:

```
body {
  background-color: background-color: #CEF6CE;
}
```

Finished code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #CEF6CE;
}
* {
  font-family: calibri;
  margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  height: 635px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.login {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 450px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 5000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 13px;
}
a:link {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="login">
        School
        <br>Community Portal
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">About</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;</td>
          <td><a href=" " style="color: #E0E0E0">Help</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: A few other suggestions:

Use width: 100% instead of 5000px for the footer.

Height 5000px should also be removed. Try setting the actual height you want (try 100 or 150px) and using "position: absolute; bottom: 0". This will stick the footer to the bottom of the page.

Comment: thank you so much for helping.. i dont have any idea how to stick the footer texts when i zoom out lol sucks all the text below goes to the left